Create pdf outline dest to first page by itext9.0.0, but jump to 2th page
I create a outline "paragraph1" target to first page by createXYZ(pdf.getPage(1), 0, 0, 0),but jump to top of page 2 when click the outline.
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(baos);

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);

Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("paragraph1").setDestination("paragraph1");
document.add(paragraph1);
PdfDestination dest = PdfExplicitDestination.createXYZ(pdf.getPage(1), 0, 0, 0);
PdfOutline coverPageOutline = pdf.getOutlines(true).addOutline("paragraph1 page");
coverPageOutline.addDestination(dest);

document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph("paragraph2").setDestination("paragraph2");
document.add(paragraph2);
dest = new PdfStringDestination("paragraph2");
PdfOutline outline = pdf.getOutlines(true).addOutline("paragraph2 string");
outline.addDestination(dest);

document.flush();
document.close();
pdf.close();


The point is createXYZ(pdf.getPage(1), 0, 0, 0).
It should be createXYZ(firstPage, 0, firstPage.getPageSize().getHeight(), 1).

Indeed. The coordinates define the top left corner of the destination. So if you use the bottom left corner of page 1 there, you'll actually see page 2. Actually more exactly, you should use getTop() instead of getHeight(), they often are the same but not always.
